# button is not defined, python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

when i run this code in python 3.5:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

def callback():
    print ("click!")

button = Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)  
top.mainloop()
```

I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'Button' is not defined
```

Comment: you already wrote `top = tkinter.Tk()` instead of `top = Tk()`. It's really obvious why `button = Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)` doesn't work. I would suggest you to guess, but there are already enough answers

Answer (score 1):

As said, "Button" is not defined

You should try :

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

def callback():
    print ("click!")

button = tkinter.Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)  
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @freidrichen response you can either use (not recommended)

```
from tkinter import *
```

or

```
import tkinter as tk
```

then

```
tk.Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)
```

Comment: Stated that it's not recommended.

Comment: FWIW, `import tkinter as tk` is _much_ better than `from tkinter import *` as the latter dumps about 130 Tkinter names into your global namespace. That's messy because it can lead to name collisions, especially if you import the contents of another module using a "star" import (and it can slow down the already-slow global name lookup process).

Comment: Agreed. It is difficult for newbies to understand this given that most of the tkinter tutorials and examples out there use `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: Indeed. The use of star imports in tkinter examples is very annoying, and plenty of other libraries do it too. At least some of them explain at the start that they do it to make writing the examples easier (and I guess it's handy when you're testing stuff in the interpreter), but they should make it clear that it's a bad thing to do in a real program. OTOH, when people are reading docs / tutorials they tend to gloss over stuff like that...

Answer (score 0):

Importing the tkinter module only gives you access to the module object (`tkinter`). You can access any of the classes therein by writing e.g. `tkinter.Button` instead of just `Button`:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Tk()

def callback():
    print ("click!")

button = tkinter.Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)  
top.mainloop()
```

Or you can specifically import the classes that you need from the module:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Button

top = tkinter.Tk()

def callback():
    print ("click!")

button = Button(top, text="OK", command=callback)  
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didnt get the error when i tried this, but the button doesnt display on the window...

Comment: Check out e.g. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm. Compare their first example to your own to see what is missing in your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response but while browsing the web with a similiar problem, I found this code. Hoping this works out for anyone who encounters this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *
```

Code taken from:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577409-python-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-selection-box/